# How to find the magnitude and phase of a complex signal (without Fourier)?

Tags: complex-numbers, signal-processing

If I had a complex signal such as: $s(t) = \cos(\pi t)*e^{-j\pi t}$, how do I go about simplifying this down so that I have an exponential which can let me calculate its magnitude and phase? This should be an easy thing, but I've forgotten a lot of concepts, which I hope someone can clear up.

Actually, if I needed to split this into its real and imaginary components, would it be easier to solve for the exponential form first, or directly rectangular?

Comment: You can expand $\cos(\pi t)={e^{j \pi t} + e^{- j \pi t} \over 2}$ but you will not find a single exponential expression.

Comment: @N74 How would you use the identity you listed to simplify the function such that you could calculate the magnitude and phase? Or get its real and imaginary components?

Comment: It is very easy to get real and imag: just distribute and use Euler expansion.

Comment: If by magnitude you mean $|s(t)|$, then recall that $|a\times b|=|a|\times|b|$ and $|e^{i\theta}|=1,\ i\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: what does the star mean? multiplication or convolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your signal is in polar form $s=re^{j\phi}$ where $r$ and $\phi$ are real. In such case, $|s|=r$ and $\measuredangle s=\phi$

Therefore, for the given signal:

$$|s(t)|=\cos(\pi t)$$
and $$\measuredangle s(t)=-\pi t $$

Comment: Thanks for replying to this question, as well as my other one! If I were to give the t variable an interval, like -2 to 2, how would that change the result, since now the cos(pi * t) function can be negative, and the magnitude of the polar form can't be negative?

Comment: Yes it will. In such case the magnitude should be $|cos(\pi t)|$ and the phase should also include the impact (phase shift $\pi$ for negative and $0$ for positive).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!